# How to pass the return value to a function in this case using python/selenium?

Tags: python, function, selenium

I am trying use a return value, elementPain, from a function and pass it to an other function , get_start_value_pain(elementpain), that needs that value. But I get an error as if the return value is out of scope. How can I pass the return value correctly and avoid the error?

```
def get_current_pain_value() -> int:
    """function to get the current pain value"""
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpathPain), "Week"))
            # use wait for "Week" because it is loaded after the pain value, hence the pain value have time to load before it is to be used in the code below

        elementPain = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathPain).get_attribute("innerText").split()[0]
        # get text, e.g. "3 Week 4" where "Week 4" is inside child-element, then use split function to get only "3".
        elementPain = int(elementPain)
        print("Current pain value is: ", elementPain)
        return elementPain

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Failed to load elementPain")

def get_start_value_pain(elementpain) -> int:
    """function to get the pain start value (through pain value and change in pain value since start)"""
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpathPainValueSinceStart)))

        elementPainValueSinceStart = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathPainValueSinceStart)
        elementPainValueSinceStart = elementPainValueSinceStart.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        elementPainValueSinceStartNumber = re.sub(pattern, newPattern, elementPainValueSinceStart)
        elementPainValueSinceStartNumber = int(elementPainValueSinceStartNumber)
        print("Change in pain (in absolute numbers) since start is: ", elementPainValueSinceStartNumber)

        painStartValue = (elementPain-elementPainValueSinceStartNumber)
        print("The pain start value is: ", painStartValue)
        return painStartValue

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Failed to load elementPainValueSinceStart")
```

Main function

```
def mainFunction():
    elementPain = get_current_pain_value()
    painStartValue = get_start_value_pain(elementPain)
```

Error:

```
  File "W:\test.py", line 257, in get_start_value_pain
    painStartValue = (elementPain-elementPainValueSinceStartNumber)
NameError: name 'elementPain' is not defined
```

Comment: Minor typo: You have the parameter of `get_start_value_pain` as `elementpain`, not `elementPain` (note the casing). Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: the above comment should have been the answer.

Comment: @cruisepandey No, this is an obvious typo, and even if it weren't and they thought Python was case-insensitive, the nature of this question means it's highly unlikely to be of use to anyone else. The below answerer should have instead voted to close it as a typo since they admit in the first sentence that they believe it's a typo.

Comment: @Carcigenicate : I agree, I see SO has `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo`, so this should have been closed since it's not gonna be use for anyone.

Comment: @Prophet : Seems like it's an SO guidelines.

Comment: No problem, but I will still leave my answer here, I hope it will be useful for the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `get_start_value_pain` method definition.
It receives parameter named `elementpain` while you trying to call it in this method as `elementPain`. So, inside the `get_start_value_pain` Python doesn't see variable named `elementPain`. This is why `NameError: name 'elementPain' is not defined` error is thrown.
You should correct it as following:

```
def get_start_value_pain(elementPain) -> int:
```